# Google Test - generate values for template class instanciation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, googletest

I am having an issue with Google Test. I have a code equivalent to what follows:

---

### A.h

```
template<int N> class A {
public:
    A() {}
    A(int n) {
        var = n;
    }
    int var;
};
```

---

### test_A.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "A.h"

template<typename T> class TestA : public ::testing::Test {};

TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestA);

TYPED_TEST_P(TestA, SomeTest){
    TypeParam x(0);
    EXPECT_EQ(x.var,0);
    ...
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestA, SomeTest);

typedef ::testing::Types<A<0>, A<1>, A<2>, A<3>, A<4>, A<5> ... A<511>, A<512>> MyTypes;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(My, TestA, MyTypes);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

---

To sum up, I want to run the test `SomeTest`on class `A` for many versions of `N`. With the [type-parameterized test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#type-parameterized-tests) developed above, the problem is that with "typed test" method, I have to write manually all versions of class `A` I want to test.

With Google Test, you can also write [value-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests), which is very convenient because you can use generators like `Range`:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(InstantiationName, TestA, ::testing::Range(0,512,1));
```

and then, you can access the values using the function `GetParam()` inside the test. This syntax would make what I want to do very easy to setup. However, it seems that the values are not resolved at compile time, and they are therefore not usable to specify templates values.

My questions are:

- Is there some syntax which is equivalent to value-parameterized testing in Google Test to specify all versions of `A` I want to test?
- If there is not, how can I generate my list of types `A<0>, ..., A<512>` to be used with type-parameterized testing?

N.B: It has to be c++11 compliant.

Comment: Regarding the second question, in c++14 [`std::make_integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) might be useful, or alternatively something along those lines: https://ideone.com/hySojY

Comment: @Caninonos: I have not told it in my post, but I am unfortunately limited to c++11. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @MikeKinghan: My question is not the same. Your answer in the post you are pointing to is out of date and does not answer my question, the code of my *test_A.cpp* works and is an equivalent to the answer you gave on the other post. My point is just to know if there is a way not to write all numbers from 0 to 512 one by one.

Comment: "The code of my test_A.cpp works". It doesn't. Even when the `...` are removed, it does
not compile. `main.cpp:14:15: error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'gtest_case_TestA_::SomeTest<A<512> >::TypeParam {aka A<512>}' requested` at `TypeParam x = 0;`
Please post something that does compile to clarify your question.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, there is no `operator =` overloading in A, but you already know it. Now it does.

Comment: You will be unable to write a `TYPED_TEST_P` to test any property of `A<N>` that depends on the value of the template parameter `N` with this approach. And if there are no such
properties then the template parameter has no purpose, and the problem does not exist. *That* is why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48890291/1362568)
proxies `N` with `std::integral_constant<std::size_t,N>` in the `test_types`.

Comment: Your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669279/create-gtest-value-parametrized-test-for-a-template-class has no advantage on the method I use in my question since you have to specify manually the value of N. Your answer in that other post works exactly the same way as in my question, so it does not answer it.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for a way to economise fingerwork in the sort of googletest
solution you've sketched above by avoiding the hardcoding of the typelist:

```
A<0>, A<1>, A<2>, A<3>, A<4>, A<5>, ... A<511>, A<512>
```

in the definition of `MyTypes`, and having it somehow generated at compiletime
given just the length of the typelist.

Regrettably, there's a very limited amount of fingerwork you can save by solving
this problem. Internally, googletest employs C++03 exclusively. So no variadic
templates, which arrived with C++11. Hence there's a hardcoded limit on the
length of the typelist in:

```
::testing::Types<T0, T1, ... Tn>
```

You're wanting a list of 513 types: the hardcoded limit is 50. After that compilation
fails.

Still, if you're going to be doing a lot with this type of googletest solution,
with typelist lengths in the N x 10 range, it might be worth your while having code
in stock to generate them the way you want.

C++14 has just the tool for jobs like this. It is [`template< class T, T... Ints> class std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).
But you say that you're restricted to `C++11`. In that case, you'll need a
hand-rolled substitute for `std::integer_sequence`. There are lots out in there
in Google land. [Jonathan Wakeley's one](https://gitorious.org/redistd/integer_seq?p=redistd:integer_seq.git;a=tree)
stands out: `std::integer_sequence` was his C++14 proposal, and his implementation
is the prototype for the C++14 standard one.

For now I'll make do with my own weedy one. Here's a header file:

**integer_seq.h**

```
#ifndef INTEGER_SEQ_H
#define INTEGER_SEQ_H

#if __cplusplus >= 201402L

#include <utility>

template<typename IntType, IntType ...Is>
using integer_seq = std::integer_sequence<IntType,Is...>;

template<typename IntType, IntType N>
using make_integer_seq = std::make_integer_sequence<IntType,N>;

#elif __cplusplus == 201103L

#include <type_traits>

template<typename IntType, IntType ...Is> struct integer_seq {};

namespace detail {

template<typename IntType, IntType Count, bool Done, IntType ...Is>
struct gen_seq;

template<typename IntType, IntType Count, IntType ...Is>
struct gen_seq<IntType, Count, false, Is...>
{
    static_assert(Count > 0,"Count must be positive");    
    using type = 
        typename gen_seq<   IntType, 
                            Count - 1, Count - 1 == 0, 
                            Count - 1, Is...
                        >::type;
};

template <typename IntType, IntType Count, IntType ...Is>
struct gen_seq<IntType, Count, true, Is...>
{
    using type = integer_seq<IntType,Is...>;
};

} // namespace detail


template<typename IntType, IntType N>
using make_integer_seq = typename detail::gen_seq<IntType,N,N == 0>::type;

#else
#error At least C++11 required :(
#endif

#endif
```

This header defines:

```
template< typename IntType, IntType ...Is> struct integer_seq;
```

which represents a sequence `Is...` of values of some integral type `IntType`, and:

```
template<typename IntType, IntType N> make_integer_seq;
```

which is an alias for the type:

```
integer_sequence<IntType,0,... N - 1>
```

If you compile in C++14 then `integer_seq` is itself just an alias for
`std::integer_sqeuence`. If C++11 then `integer_seq` is hand-rolled.

Once you've got template `integer_seq`, you can use it to get some leverage
on googletest's template `::testing::Types`. Here's another header file:

**indexed_type_list**

```
#ifndef INDEXED_TYPE_LIST_H
#define INDEXED_TYPE_LIST_H

#include <cstddef>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "integer_seq.h"

template<typename IntType, template<IntType> class T, typename Seq>
struct indexed_type_list;

template<typename IntType, template<IntType> class T, IntType ...Is>
struct indexed_type_list<IntType,T,integer_seq<IntType,Is...>>
{
    using type = ::testing::Types<T<Is>...>;
};

template<typename IntType, template<IntType> class T,  std::size_t Size>
using indexed_type_list_t =
    typename indexed_type_list<IntType,T,make_integer_seq<IntType,Size>>::type;

#endif
```

which defines:

```
template<typename IntType, template<IntType> class T,  IntType Size>
indexed_type_list_t;
```

such that, given some integral type `IntType`, a number `Size` of that type,
and some unary non-type template `template<IntType> class T`, then:

```
indexed_type_list_t<IntType,T,Size>
```

is an alias for:

```
::testing::Types<T<0>,... T<Size - 1>>;
```

which is what you're after. `indexed_type_list` is admittedly a very lame name
for this concept, but my imagaination fails me.

Now we ready to roll. Here's how we'd adapt your specimen solution:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "indexed_type_list.h"
#include "A.h"

template<typename T> class TestA : public ::testing::Test{};

TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestA);

TYPED_TEST_P(TestA, SomeTest){
    TypeParam x(0);
    EXPECT_EQ(x.var,0);
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestA, SomeTest);

using MyTypes = indexed_type_list_t<int,A,50>;

INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(My, TestA, MyTypes);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile and link:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
$ g++ -o testrunner main.o -lgtest -pthread
```

And it runs like:

```
$ ./testrunner
[==========] Running 50 tests from 50 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from My/TestA/0, where TypeParam = A<0>
[ RUN      ] My/TestA/0.SomeTest
[       OK ] My/TestA/0.SomeTest (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from My/TestA/0 (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from My/TestA/1, where TypeParam = A<1>
[ RUN      ] My/TestA/1.SomeTest
[       OK ] My/TestA/1.SomeTest (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from My/TestA/1 (0 ms total)

...
...

[----------] 1 test from My/TestA/48, where TypeParam = A<48>
[ RUN      ] My/TestA/48.SomeTest
[       OK ] My/TestA/48.SomeTest (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from My/TestA/48 (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from My/TestA/49, where TypeParam = A<49>
[ RUN      ] My/TestA/49.SomeTest
[       OK ] My/TestA/49.SomeTest (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from My/TestA/49 (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 50 tests from 50 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 50 tests.
```

So that's your problem solved. It's all optional for here on.

**The flip side**

There's a fatal design flaw in this approach to testing any class template
over a range of non-type template parameters. It was there before we solved
the problem of generating the typelist for `::testing::Types`, and it's still
there.

In real applications, proficiently designed, you don't come across a class template like the
`template<int N> class A` defined in `A.h`, where the template parameter `N`
is not used at all, either in the template definition or for template specializations.
That template parameter has no practical purpose. The definition of `A` might
as well be:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    A(int n) {
        var = n;
    }
    int var;
};
```

Suppose that instead of `A` we had to deal with a marginally more
lifelike template:

**dot_matrix.h**

```
#ifndef DOT_MATRIX_H
#define DOT_MATRIX_H

#include <array>

template<std::size_t N>
struct dot_matrix
{
    bool get(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) const {
        return _square.at(x).at(y);
    }
    void set(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) {
        _square.at(x).at(y) = true;
        ++_filled;
    }
    void clear(std::size_t x, std::size_t y){
        _square.at(x).at(y) = false;
        --_filled;
    }

    unsigned filled() const {
        return _filled;
    }

    unsigned vacant() const {
        return area() - _filled;
    }

    static constexpr std::size_t side() {
        return N * 2;
    }

    static constexpr std::size_t area() {
        return side() * side();
    }

private:
    unsigned _filled;
    std::array<std::array<bool,N>,N> _square;
};

#endif
```

Supposedly,`template<std::size_t N> struct dot_matrix` generically
encapsulates a fixed-size square dot matrix of size `N` x `N`. I say *supposedly*
because right now it's let down by a bug - true, an unrealistically obvious bug
- that we'd hope to flush out by googletest unit-testing.

You draw the straw to code the unit-testing and get everything setup up for
`TYPED_TEST_CASE_P` style testing, with:

```
using MyTypes = ::testing::Types<dot_matrix<0>,... dot_matrix<49>>;
```

It doesn't matter whether you compiletime-generate

```
dot_matrix<0>,... dot_matrix<49>
```

or code it hard way.

You write a bunch of `TYPED_TEST_P`s, for instance:

```
TYPED_TEST_P(TestDotMatrix,IsSquare){
    TypeParam matrix;
    auto side = matrix.side();
    EXPECT_EQ(matrix.area(),side * side));
}

TYPED_TEST_P(TestDotMatrix, IsConsistent){
    TypeParam matrix;
    auto cap = matrix.filled() + matrix.vacant();
    EXPECT_EQ(matrix.area(),cap));
}
...
```

The team leader code reviews and spots:-

- A bug in `dot_matrix<N>`. It doesn't encapsulate an `N` x `N` dot matrix.
  Actually, it encapsulates a `2N` x `2N` dot matrix.
- You haven't got a test that verifies that `dot_matrix<N>` contains an
  `N` x `N` matrix.

You get back on the case to fix this oversight:-

```
TYPED_TEST_P(TestDotMatrix, SizeIsRight){
    TypeParam matrix;
    EXPECT_EQ(???,matrix.side());
}
```

But you can't. You cannot fill in `???`, because `TypeParam` is just
a `dot_matrix<N>` for some value of `N` *that the test does not know*, and that `N`
is what needs replace `???`.

Because none of the tests know the value of `N` with which their `TypeParam`
was instantiated, they can all test only behaviours of `dot_matrix<N>` that
are invariant with respect to `N`, just like that:

```
TYPED_TEST_P(TestA, SomeTest){
    TypeParam x(0);
    EXPECT_EQ(x.var,0);
}
```

above. Testing a behaviour that doesn't vary with `N` for 50 different values of
`N` isn't useful. It *is* useful to have tests for those `N`-invariant behaviours, of course.
Just not for 50 different values of `N`, or indeed, more than one.

The behaviours that *do* vary with `N` also need to be tested. Like: Does
a `dot_matrix<N>` report the right size and area *for that* `N`?

It is for *these* tests that your googletest solution requires a range that
varies `N` in instantiations of the `TYPED_TEST_P`s. And here is what needs to be
be appreciated to get those `TYPED_TEST_P`s out the '???' quandry:-

The fact that a `template struct dot_matrix<std::size_t N>` is under test is *invariant*.
None of the tests needs to be given this information: the test range doesn't need to
convey it. The only thing that varies is `N`. The value of `N` is the one thing that each test needs
to know. The range that you require to instantiate the tests is *a range of values of* `N`.

That presents a difficulty, at first sight, for a googletest solution.

Googletest offers a framework for generating [Value Parameterized Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#value-parameterized-tests)
that can instantiate a `TEST_P` for each of a range of *values* given
as *runtime* arguments to `::testing::Values(...)`.

Googletest also offers frameworks for generating [Typed Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#typed-tests)
and [Type Parameterized Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#type-parameterized-tests)
that can instantiate a `TYPED_TEST` or `TYPED_TEST_P` for each of a range of *types* given
as *compiletime* template arguments to `::testing::Types<...>`.

But *we* need a range of values of a non-type template parameter. C++ requires
such a parameter to be a compiletime integral constant. The googletest options for test ranges
do not include *a range of compiletime integral constants*.

Happily, C++11 or later comes to the rescue with a *way to map an integral
constant uniquely to a type*. It is [`template< class IntType, IntType v > struct std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant).
For any constant `N` of integral type `IntType`:

```
struct std::integral_constant<IntType,N>;
```

is the uniquely mapped type, and from that type you can retrieve a compiletime
constant `N` as:

```
std::integral_constant<IntType,N>::value;
```

So here in bare essense is the googletest solution:

```
...
using MyTypes =
    ::testing::Types<std::integral_constant<0>,...std::integral_constant<49>>;

...
...

TYPED_TEST_P(TestDotMatrix, SizeIsRight){
    dot_matrix<TypeParam::value> matrix;
    EXPECT_EQ(TypeParam::value,matrix.side());
}
```

and here's a fully working example, with the `testing::Types` range
compiletime-generated as before.

A new header:

**integral_constant_typelist.h**

```
#ifndef INTEGRAL_CONSTANT_TYPELIST_H
#define INTEGRAL_CONSTANT_TYPELIST_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "integer_seq.h"

template<typename IntType, IntType Start,typename Seq>
struct integral_constant_typelist;

template<typename IntType, IntType Start,IntType ...Is>
struct integral_constant_typelist<IntType,Start,integer_seq<IntType,Is...>>
{
    using type =
        ::testing::Types<std::integral_constant<IntType,Start + Is>...>;
};

template<typename IntType, IntType Start,std::size_t Size>
using integral_constant_typelist_t =
    typename integral_constant_typelist<
        IntType,Start,make_integer_seq<IntType,Size>
    >::type;

#endif
```

This header, unlike `indexed_type_list.h`, is not badly named. It's
a candidate for your googletest toolkit. It defines:

```
template<typename IntType, IntType Start,std::size_t Size>
integral_constant_typelist_t
```

to be the type of:

```
::testing::Types<std::integral_constant<IntType,Start>,...
                    std::integral_constant<IntType,Start + (Size - 1)>
```

So e.g.

```
integral_constant_typelist_t<int,3,10>
```

is the type of:

```
::testing::Types<
    std::integral_constant<int,3>,...std::integral_constant<int,12>>
```

Then here's a test suite for `dot_matrix<N>`:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "integral_constant_typelist.h"
#include "dot_matrix.h"

using arbitrary = std::integral_constant<std::size_t,42>;

// A fixture template for N-variant tests
template<
    typename T // = `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>`, for some `N`
> struct TestDotMatrixVariant : ::testing::Test
{
    using int_type = typename T::value_type; // = std::size_t
    static constexpr int_type N_param() {
        return T::value;    // = N
    }
    using test_type = dot_matrix<N_param()>;
    dot_matrix<N_param()> const & get_specimen() const {
        return _specimen;
    }
    dot_matrix<N_param()> & get_specimen() {
        return _specimen;
    }
protected:
    test_type _specimen;
};

// A fixture for invariant tests
struct TestDotMatrixInvariant : TestDotMatrixVariant<arbitrary>{};

// Invariant test
TEST_F(TestDotMatrixInvariant,IsSquare){
    auto const & specimen = get_specimen();
    auto side = specimen.side();
    EXPECT_EQ(specimen.area(),side * side);
}

// Another invariant test
TEST_F(TestDotMatrixInvariant, IsConsistent){
    auto const & specimen = get_specimen();
    auto cap = specimen.filled() + specimen.vacant();
    EXPECT_EQ(specimen.area(),cap);
}

// Yet another invariant test
TEST_F(TestDotMatrixInvariant,OutOfRangeGetXThrows)
{
    auto const & specimen = get_specimen();
    auto x = specimen.side() + 1;
    EXPECT_THROW(specimen.get(x,0),std::out_of_range);
}

// More invariant tests...

// An N-variant test case
TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestDotMatrixVariant);

// An N-variant test
TYPED_TEST_P(TestDotMatrixVariant,SizeIsRight){
    EXPECT_EQ(this->N_param(),this->get_specimen().side());
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestDotMatrixVariant,SizeIsRight);

using dot_matrices_0_50 = integral_constant_typelist_t<std::size_t,0,50>;

INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(N_0_to_50,TestDotMatrixVariant,dot_matrices_0_50);

// More N-variant test cases and N-variant tests...

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile and link:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
$ g++ -o testrunner main.o -lgtest -pthread
```

Run:

```
$ ./testrunner
[==========] Running 53 tests from 51 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from TestDotMatrixInvariant
[ RUN      ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.IsSquare
[       OK ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.IsSquare (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.IsConsistent
[       OK ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.IsConsistent (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.OutOfRangeGetXThrows
[       OK ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.OutOfRangeGetXThrows (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from TestDotMatrixInvariant (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/0, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 0ul>
[ RUN      ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/0.SizeIsRight
[       OK ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/0.SizeIsRight (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/0 (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/1, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 1ul>
[ RUN      ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/1.SizeIsRight
main.cpp:58: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  this->N_param()
    Which is: 1
  this->get_specimen().side()
    Which is: 2
[  FAILED  ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/1.SizeIsRight, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 1ul> (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/1 (0 ms total)
...
...
...
[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 49ul>
[ RUN      ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49.SizeIsRight
main.cpp:58: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  this->N_param()
    Which is: 49
  this->get_specimen().side()
    Which is: 98
[  FAILED  ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49.SizeIsRight, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 49ul> (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49 (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 53 tests from 51 test cases ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 4 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 49 tests, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/1.SizeIsRight, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 1ul>
...
...
...
[  FAILED  ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49.SizeIsRight, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 49ul>

49 FAILED TESTS
```

All of the invariant tests passed. Variant test `SizeIsRight` passed, as it should, for `dot_matrix<0>`. Then it
failed, as it should, for `dot_matrix<1>` through `dot_matrix<49>`.

Better debug:

```
static constexpr std::size_t side() {
    // return N * 2; <-- Wrong
    return N; // <-- Right
}
```

Then:

```
$ ./testrunner
[==========] Running 53 tests from 51 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from TestDotMatrixInvariant
[ RUN      ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.IsSquare
[       OK ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.IsSquare (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.IsConsistent
[       OK ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.IsConsistent (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.OutOfRangeGetXThrows
[       OK ] TestDotMatrixInvariant.OutOfRangeGetXThrows (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from TestDotMatrixInvariant (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/0, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 0ul>
[ RUN      ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/0.SizeIsRight
[       OK ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/0.SizeIsRight (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/0 (0 ms total)
...
...
...
[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49, where TypeParam = std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 49ul>
[ RUN      ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49.SizeIsRight
[       OK ] N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49.SizeIsRight (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from N_0_to_50/TestDotMatrixVariant/49 (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 53 tests from 51 test cases ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 53 tests.
```

All good.