# C++ templates and parameterized Google test

Tags: c++, googletest

Let's say I am writing a template for a class called `class_a`:

```
bool test_success;
template <uint32_t len>
class class_a
{
    uint32_t do_something(void)
    {
        return len+1;
    }
};
```

And I want to test the class with a series of different `len` values, so i'm doing a parameterized test.

Now, the problem arises when writing the test fixture:

```
class test_classa : public::testing::TestWithParam<    uint32_t    >
{
    void SetUp() override
    {
        test_success = false;
        // constexpr uint32_t a_len = GetParam(); //compiler error 1 (See below)
        // const uint32_t a_len = GetParam(); //compiler error 2 (See below)
        constexpr uint32_t a_len = 5; //Works! But that's not using the test parameter!
        class_a<a_len> a_test;
        if (a_test.do_something() == (a_len+1))
        {
           test_success = true;
        }
    }

    void TearDown() override
    {

    }
};
```

And the rest of my code goes as the following:

```
TEST_P(test_classa, test_classa) {
    EXPECT_EQ (test_success, true);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(
        class_a,
        test_classa,
        ::testing::Values(
            10,
            20
            ));
```

So can anybody help me how to get this done? Is it even possible ?

**EDIT:**

As requested, here are the compile errors:
(1) constexpr variable 'a_len' must be initialized by a constant expression
(2) non-type template argument is not a constant expression

Comment: So what's your problem? Is it a compile error? Or a weird runtime routine?

Comment: It's a compile error, sorry i missed that detail, i'll complete my question.

Comment: Please see the updated answer and once more, try including as much information about the problem as you can. It's not easy to guess what is the compiler message just looking at the code. Even more, when some part of the code is not available, it becomes harder to guess

Comment: Why did you consider using the `template` argument as a value? Why not to pass it to the function?

Comment: Well @arsdever, obviously, in my oversimplified example, it does not make sense to use a template. but in the real life class i'll be testing, I *have* to use a template (why I'm using a template it's a whole other issue...)

Comment: To summarize, you have to know the `template` value at compile-time. The compile-time solution is to use either another `template` or `constexpr`. If I knew more about the exact problem, I could have proposed a better solution, but as for now, it is just information I can share with you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you sure that you got the idea it's test fixture? I do fully understand the problem, and i was actually fully expecting it when writing the code. The problem is that i don't know how to write a test fixture that will test my class with different template values.

Comment: Having said "different template values" you mean `uint32_t` values? If yes, then consider having it as a function argument. In case the type might be different, have the template to accept typename T as a template argument and the function to accept arguments of type T.

Comment: Having said "different template values" you mean uint32_t values? Yes.

But as i said before, If passing the value as a function argument is not an option, i need to use templates.

Comment: Then maybe you could say what is your GetParam function, what it does, why it's there? You tell nothing but want to get a help.

Comment: GetParam() is part of Google Test. Pardon me for asking, but are you familiar with google test? (http://sandordargo.com/blog/2019/04/24/parameterized-testing-with-gtest)

Comment: I'm not. For short. If the function you use is constexpr, then it's possible. Otherwise, it's not.

Comment: @IbrahimK. Check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890291/google-test-generate-values-for-template-class-instanciation I think is is the same problem

Answer (score 0):

At least you derive the class incorrectly. Try deriving

```
class test_classa : public testing::TestWithParam<    uint32_t    >
```

## EDIT

After details provided, I see you are assigning a function call to a `constexpr`, which might work in case your function is also a `constexpr` one, because `constexpr` are resolved compile-time. I believe the compiler message includes a similar message like "Function must be a `constexpr`".

For the second case, I don't know much of details about your `GetParam` function, and as you didn't include the whole compiler message, I believe, that reading it carefully will hint you where to find the problem to solve.

If you're not able to find it by then, please update the question and try providing as much information as you can when posting questions here.

## EDIT 2

Now I see the second problem. It is trying to instantiate a template using `const` variable. This is impossible, because the value of `const variable` is getting during runtime, and the templates are instantiated during compilation. You cannot do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks. I did change that, but it did not help (And the compiler never complained though.)